# Using multiple iframe with different sessions through a proxy server

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm developing an automation tool using javascript/jQuery.

To manipulate the DOM I've tunneled all iframe/browser access through an proxy server to have all them on same domain.

All this is working fine! But my end point app is a transactional jsp/servlet database and I wanna have multiple access to it.

I guess, because the proxy 'tunneling' all access through proxy has the same session, wich is not desirable since I need multiple access to the app, and to do this I must create different sessions.

I'm trying to figure out how to achieve a unique sessionID for each Iframe/browser pointing to the same web app passing through the same (?) proxy server, roughly:

```
iframe ---\
iframe -----> browser ---> apache proxy ---> jsp transactional app
iframe ---/
```

I was sniffing the traffic on FireFox (FireBug) and all iframes has the same session ID. That's not exclusively on iframe, even if I start another browser and use the link passing trhough the proxy I keep the same session ID.

Using Apache http Server 2.2.20 (win32).

Proxy config (if useful):

```
ProxyPass  /bbb http://xxx/bbb/
ProxyPassReverse /bbb/ http://xxx/bbb/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do the iframes src attributes point to the same domain or subdomain?**

Remember that Session is implemented through cookies and that cookies are shared through the domain and subdomains they belong to, eg:

If Cookie belongs to *yourdomain.com* then *subdomain.yourdomain.com* has access to it

but

If Cookie belongs to *subdomain.yourdomain.com* then *yourdomain.com* or *subdomain1.subdomain.yourdomain.com* **DOES NOT** have access to it

And it doesn´t matter if it's an iframe or another browser window or tab...

Comment: Yes, all src points to the same domain. So what I guess is that you suggest that it should be possible to config my proxy to 'emulate' subdomains to create different session ids on my clients?